# Perl Command Line- If string found replace next line

Tags: perl

I am a total Perl noob and trying to figure out if this thing can be done. I have a text file which contains data like formula names, and then the formula in the next line (single line) like so -

```
Formula Name = abc formula for TAT
count(a)+500
```

The formula name is unique. I need to search for the formula name, and then replace the formula in the next line. What is the best way to do this? Can it be done with the perl command line?

It seems that the command line reads the file one line at a time and i will need to use the `-0NNN` switch to be able to operate on multiple lines. But I am not sure how to use this.

Thanks in advance!

J

Comment: Can you please give an example of replacement?

Comment: Any line... say count(b)+ 600

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is possible to use perl in this case. But right now I know a way to solve in SED. It helps?

```
$ cat xxx
Formula Name blablabla
cos(x) + i sen(x)

other stuff
$ sed '/Formula Name/{n;s/.*/e=mc2/;}' xxx
Formula Name blablabla
e=mc2

other stuff
```

to do this in perl we need a few more lines, I will try some examples and write here later.

EDIT:

```
$ perl -ne 's/.*/e=mc2/ if $find; print; $find=/Formula Name/;' xxx
Formula Name blablabla
e=mc2

other stuff
```

Comment: Thanks! But I need a perl solution sadly.

Comment: I tried perl -ne "s/.*/e=mc2/ if $find; print; $find=/Formula Name/;" test.txt
 but it ends up printing the file, not modifying it :(

Comment: Interesting - I tried perl.exe -pi -i.vxtmp -e "s/.*/e=mc2/ if $find; print; $find=/Formula Name/;" test.txt
 It works but ends up duplicating every line in the file! Any way to fix that?

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to use the `-0777` option, you can simply read and throw away a line, then add whatever you want to the current line.

```
perl -pe 'if (/Formula Name/) { <>; $_ .= "new formula$/"; }' filename
```

I used `$/` to represent your newline, since it should be the same as what readline uses. But you can use `\n` as well. To do in-place edit, simply add the `-i.bak` switch.

Comment: I tried this perl -pi -i.vixmp -e  "if (/Formula Name/) { <>; $_ .= "new formula\n"; }" test.txt, but it gives me the following error -syntax error at -e line 1, near "}continue"
Missing right curly or square bracket at -e line 1, at end of line
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.

Comment: @Jai If you're using Windows, you need to double quote the program line, in which case you cannot use double quotes for the new formula. Use `qq(new formula$/)` instead. You *will* need interpolation for both `$/` and `\n`, so `qq()` is necessary.

Comment: That works too! Thanks! Should have mentioned it was windows before.

Answer (score 2):

`bash` syntax:

```
perl -i.vixmp -pe'
    s/\Q$name\E/\U$name/ if $name;
    ($name) = /Formula Name = (\S+)/;
' file
```

`cmd` syntax:

```
perl -i.vixmp -pe"
    s/\Q$name\E/\U$name/ if $name;
    ($name) = /Formula Name = (\S+)/;
" file
```

You didn't specify exactly what needed to be replaced, and what it needed to be replaced with, so replaced the formula name with its uppercase. Adjust as needed.

If you're looking for a specific formula instead of all of them, just change `\S+` with the name of the formula you want to find.

*Important*: You must remove the line breaks from the `cmd` version for it to work. (I used them for readability.) You can remove the line breaks from the `bash` version, but it's optional.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a substitution regular expression.  You can match each line of the text against a regular expresion and then replace the second part as you want, for example something like this should work :

```
$repl = "replacement formula for the line";
$line =~ s/(Formula Name\s=\s)([\w]\d]+)$/$1 $repl/;
```